# Java RegEx - Illegal character dot

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String filter = "a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß-\\.";
"^[^" + filter + "]*$", ""

inputtext.replaceAll("^[^" + filter + "]*$", "");
```

This Java RegEx filter should remove all characters from inputtext except the characters in filter, but I'm getting an exception that says that the dot is not allowed. I already escaped the dot with two slashes.
What's wrong?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to escape a dot in a character class. From the javadoc: "For instance, the regular expression . loses its special meaning inside a character class, while the expression - becomes a range forming metacharacter." But, as the others pointed out, it's the range metacharacter that's causing the real problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `-` to the end:

```
String filter = "a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß.-";
```

A dash indicates a character range and a dot is not a valid end of a range. You also do not want to define a range there. Moving it to the end solves the problem.

Btw. if you want to remove all characters that do not match your filter you need to change the replace:

```
inputtext = inputtext.replaceAll("[^" + filter + "]", "");
```

the way you have it, it will only replace if all characters are not in that class.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine for me:

```
    String str = "afjlajfdl;f2.3232A,&^%DFDF-";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]", ""));
```

And produces output:

```
afjlajfdlf2.3232ADFDF-
```

Generally you should not escape `.` into `[]` and for replace pattern you should not specify start and end of the string (^, $) as well as multiplexer `*`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the full-stop (dot) in your regex, but the minus-sign in front of it. If you escape that as well, things work better:

```
String filter = "a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\\-\\.";
```

On a side note: I'm not sure if using the very first and very last character that you use in your regex have the desired effect. Perhaps you should remove them?

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot in a range. `"a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\\-."` will work fine.